# Create Custom SignUp form in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I am new to Moodle. My client need something special in SignUp form. I want to know how I can change code of signup form which is created through the Moodle Dashboard?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? Are there any examples therein that could help you? Is there a theme system where you can add templates? Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617350/how-to-create-a-custom-form-in-moodle) of any help?

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 (for developers). Create your own authentication plugin https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins and use it instead of standard auth_email for self-registration

Option 2 (for administrators). Create custom profile fields and add them to the registration form. This does not require developer but might not be flexible enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can change signup form in [your Moodle www dir]/login/signup_form.php

Maybe [Form API docs](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Form_API) will be helpful for you.

Comment: very bad practice to do core hacks, especially when it is possible to do this as a plugin

Comment: You are right, at most cases it's bad practice which has only one advantage for beginner developer - maximum problem solving speed. And of course it may lead to some problems in project future.